# Map<Integer,List<String>> creation with out pre java8 for loops

Tags: java, list

I want to create the zoneId to Domain list map from a list where each Zone will have multiple domains. The following is my code, Is it possible to write the code without the pre-java8 for loops

```
 private Map<Integer, List<String>> buildZoneIdDomainMap() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Map<Integer, List<String>> retVal = new HashMap<>();
    List<DomainCustomerZoneDtls>  dczList = null;
    List<String> strList = null;

    Map<Integer,List<DomainCustomerZoneDtls>> map = 
             domainCustzoneList.parallelStream().collect(                              
     Collectors.groupingBy(DomainCustomerZoneDtls::getCustomerZoneId));
     for(Map.Entry<Integer, List<DomainCustomerZoneDtls>> 
        entryVal:map.entrySet()) {
        dczList = entryVal.getValue();
        strList = new ArrayList<>();
        for(DomainCustomerZoneDtls dcz:dczList) {
            strList.add(dcz.getDomain());
        }
        retVal.put(entryVal.getKey(), strList);
    }
    return retVal;
 }

 package test.support;
 import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
 import lombok.Data;
 import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
 @Data
 @NoArgsConstructor
 @AllArgsConstructor
 public class DomainCustomerZoneDtls {
       private String  domain;
       private Integer customerZoneId;
 }
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by "without the pre-java8 for loops". Are you trying to rewrite the for-each loops into stream operations? What is your motivation for doing so?

Comment: yes, i was trying to rewrite the for-each loops into stream operations

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a [downstream collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#groupingBy-java.util.function.Function-java.util.stream.Collector-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `Collector` for this.

***Code***

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DomainCustomerZoneDtls> domainCustomerZoneDtls = Arrays.asList(
                new DomainCustomerZoneDtls("abc", 1),
                new DomainCustomerZoneDtls("abc", 2),
                new DomainCustomerZoneDtls("abc", 3),
                new DomainCustomerZoneDtls("efg", 1),
                new DomainCustomerZoneDtls("efg", 2)
        );

    Map<Integer, List<String>> integerListMap = buildZoneIdDomainMap(domainCustomerZoneDtls);

    System.out.println(integerListMap);
}

private static Map<Integer, List<String>> buildZoneIdDomainMap(List<DomainCustomerZoneDtls> domainCustomerZoneDtls) {
    return domainCustomerZoneDtls.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(DomainCustomerZoneDtls::getCustomerZoneId,
                    Collector.of(
                            ArrayList::new,
                            (strings, domainCustomerZoneDtls1) -> strings.add(domainCustomerZoneDtls1.getDomain()),
                            (strings, strings2) -> {
                                strings.addAll(strings2);
                                return strings;
                            }
                    )));
}
```

***Output***

```
{1=[abc, efg], 2=[abc, efg], 3=[abc]}
```

Comment: Yes, It has worked. Btw what the best sites to get grip on the java8 programming constructs. Though how much I read, not able to apply to the programming problems properly :(

Comment: Glad it helped. To be honest there isn't one site that I could recommend. It really depends what exactly you're trying to learn. Maybe start here : https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/

Comment: @GarrethGolding your downstream collector is much more complicated that it needs to be. `Collectors.mapping(DomainCustomerZoneDtls::getDomain, Collectors.toList())` will do it.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @sprinter .. I wasn't aware of the `Collectors.mapping()` method.

Comment: @SriramMargapuri It's in my answer - you just need to convert to your domain (i.e. replace the class names)

Answer (score 1):

Converting to a simpler case for clarity. I hope it's equivalent - let me know if not.

```
public class Mapping {
    private static List<Person> people = List.of(
        new Person("Fred", 15), new Person("Anne", 17), new Person("Joe", 15));

    private static class Person {
        private final String name;
        private final int age;

        public Person(String name, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.age = age;
        }

        int getAge() {
            return age;
        };

        String getName() {
            return name;
        };
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map<Integer,List<String>> ageMap = people.stream()
            .collect(groupingBy(Person::getAge, mapping(Person::getName, toList())));
        ageMap.forEach((age, names) -> System.out.println(age + ":" + names));
    }
}
```

Comment: Sure. I will try this. What the mapping function will do. I am getting a syntax error there

Comment: I converted to a full example so you can see it in context. The mapping function coverts the stream of `Person` objects to a stream of names and then collects in a list.